# npm install react-google-login not working

Tags: reactjs, npm

i am using following command to install react-google-login for react npm install react-google-login but its not working

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: loginwithgooleapp@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!   react-google-login@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/Baran/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Baran/.npm/_logs/2022-03-30T04_33_37_205Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: try ```npm install react-google-login --legacy-peer-deps```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

try using

```
npm install react-google-login --force
```

or

```
npm install react-google-login --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: But why?  And, which is better?